# Resizing an image when the cell in a UICollectionView has been expanded

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a photo gallery (UICollectionView) which populates itself with the photos from the user's phone. Only single selection is allowed and whenever an image is tapped, an enlarged version of the image would be shown to the user. Well, at least that's how i want it.

The problem is with the enlarging portion. The cell itself will have it's dimensions increased but the image still remains the same.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        if indexPath == largePhotoIndexPath && indexPath.item != 0
        { 
            if let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            {
                var imgCell = imageCell as PhotoThumbnailCollectionViewCell
                var imgToEnlarge = imgCell.getThumbnailImage() as UIImage

                let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(imgToEnlarge.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
                imgToEnlarge.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

                let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            }

            return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        }

        return self.cellDefSize! //normal size
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah....i am very embarrassed about this.
I forgot to add the constraints for the UIImageView. Once added, the problem was solved. All that is left is some fine tuning.